# JQuery Unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jquery unobtrusive in my bootstrap modals to validate form.
so I have file field that user select a picture but it is not required but still when user submit the form still required
this my model :

```
 public class CreateSlide
    {
    
        [MaxFileUploadSize(1*1024*1024,ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.uploadSize)]
        public IFormFile Picture { get;  set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)]
        public string HeadingText { get;  set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)]
        public string TitleText { get;  set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)]
        public string Text { get;  set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)]
        public string BtnText { get;  set; }
    }
```

I remove the required data annotation in model an i try to remove it with jquery in the form but it is not working

Comment: Please explain how is it not working.

Comment: for example picture property is nullable in the model that recieve from form but when user submit the information still when picture field is null jquery unobtrusive not allowing  submit information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I have file field that user select a picture but it is not required
> but still when user submit the form still required

You have two options to try. Hope it can help you.

Option 1 , remove below code from your project.csproj file. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

```
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Option2 , add`?` like:

```
public IFormFile ? Picture { get;  set; }
```

**Update**

The structure:
[image]

IndexModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public CreateSlide CreateSlide { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public void OnPost(CreateSlide createSlide)
        {

        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
    @page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>CreateSlide</h4>
<hr />
<button id="btnShowModal" type="button"> Upload </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="btnHideModal" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">  ×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CreateSlide.Picture" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CreateSlide.Picture" type="file" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CreateSlide.Picture" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CreateSlide.HeadingText" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CreateSlide.HeadingText" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CreateSlide.HeadingText" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CreateSlide.TitleText" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CreateSlide.TitleText" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CreateSlide.TitleText" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CreateSlide.Text" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CreateSlide.Text" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CreateSlide.Text" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CreateSlide.BtnText" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="CreateSlide.BtnText" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CreateSlide.BtnText" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {                                 
                $("#Modal").modal('show');
            });
 $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

CreateSlide:

```
public class CreateSlide
    {
        public IFormFile Picture { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string HeadingText { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TitleText { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BtnText { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdi Khorshidi, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.

Comment: it's not working when I make a property nullable (add ?) all of my model properties become nullable and  deleting  (<nullable> enable</nullable>)  in csProj not working

Comment: @Mahdi Khorshidi     How is not woking? Could you explain it more ?

Comment: Look in the first solution that you said add ? to property to make it nullable , So I did an the proplem is that this '?' effect the other properties in this model and make all propertie nullable and the same issue for the second solution tha you said

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi  I don't have `[MaxFileUploadSize(1*1024*1024,ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.uploadSize)]` , and use `[Required]` to instead  `[Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)]` , then use one of two option , see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sESUc.gif

Comment: i made this annotaion by my self

Comment: and how can i show the error message that I want if  I remove the 'ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.requiredField)' ?

Comment: @Mahdi Khorshidi Could you share your annotaion made by yourself ?

Comment: wich version of  .net you are using ?

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi I use .net5 in the before jpg and in this I use .net6 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMt4U.gif , the same result

Comment: can isee the structure of your project because i create my classe in a class library as single project and i refrence them to pages and i use razor pages

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi my project is a mvc project, I will do a razor page for you

Comment: i think its  better to chat and in the end comment the result here ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms  It says You'll need 20 reputation to talk here.

Comment: we can do it in messenger like telegram this is my id @Mahdisys81

Comment: @Mahdi Khorshidi   I'm sorry, according to the rules of the forum, 
we can't ,
but you can ask your questions here, 
and we will help you solve them

Comment: no problem 
i'm still need help in this one 
what did you do with razor pages?

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi the same one of the two option as before,  see https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgVrl.gif

Comment: i'm using in modal i think because of that unobtrusive it's not worikin well

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi  please see it in the modal  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWJvL.gif

Comment: thanks it seems like ihave a problem some where in my project

Comment: what is "_ValidationScriptsPartial"?

Comment: @MahdiKhorshidi   There are `<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>` in _ValidationScriptsPartial